# Adding a key value pair in a dictionary inside a dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, c#-4.0, key-value

I have a dictionary < string,object > which has a mapping of a string and a dictionary < string,int >. How do I add a key value pair in the inside dictionary < string ,int > ?

```
Dictionary <string,object> dict = new Dictionary <string,object>();
Dictionary <string,int> insideDict = new Dictionary <string,int>();
// ad some values in insideDict
dict.Add("blah",insideDict);
```

So now the dict has a dictionary mapped with a string.Now I want to separately add values to the insideDict.
I tried

```
dict["blah"].Add();
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: @GiladGreen Added.

Comment: Compare it to my answer.
The comment you added before the top .Add isn't correct - that line adds to the outer dictionary an item with the key "blah" and the insideDict as it's value.

The second .Add - you need to give that function some parameters - it requires another key and value (for the inner dictionary)

Comment: @GiladGreen That comment was for the 2nd statement meaning to add some key value pairs for innerDict

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like below

```
Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
dict.Add("1", new Dictionary<string, int>());
```

(OR) if you already have defined the inner dictionary then

```
Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
Dictionary<string, int> innerdict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
dict.Add("1", innerdict); // added to outer dictionary
string key = "1";
((Dictionary<string, int>)dict[key]).Add("100", 100); // added to inner dictionary
```

Per your comment *tried this but screwed up somewhere*

You didn't got it cause of your below line where you forgot to cast the inner dictionary value to `Dictionary<string, int>` since your outer dictionary value is `object`. You should rather have your outer dictionary declared strongly typed.

```
dict.Add("blah",insideDict); //forgot casting here
```

Comment: I want to be able to add new key value pairs to the innerDict where innerDict already has some values.

Comment: @vishallc, added an explanation as why you got screwed up. you may check the answer again.

Answer (score 9):

Do you mean something like this?

```
var collection = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>();
collection.Add("some key", new Dictionary<string, int>());
collection["some key"].Add("inner key", 0);
```

Comment: I want to be able to add new key value pairs to the innerDict.

Comment: Just like my third line. When I did collection["some key"] I got the reference of the value of that key - which is the string to int dictionary. and then just .Add("some other key", 2);

Answer (score 0):

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,TValue>> dic = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,TValue>>();
```

Replace the TValue with your value type.